# <picture>: if multiple media queries match, which one has priority?

Tags: html, media-queries, responsive-images, srcset

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="smaller.image" media="(max-width: 799px)">
  <source srcset="bigger.image"  media="(min-width: 800px)">
  <source srcset="exactly.image" media="(width: 801px)">
</picture>
```

In this example, if your viewport is exactly `801px` in width. Which image is preferred and why?

`bigger.image` or `exactly.image`?

is the specify of the query part of the consideration? or the order of the `<source />` element?

Answer (score 2):

[According to the Specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-source-element) the file `bigger.image` will be used since it was the first query that matched the current viewport:

> The media attributes may also be present. If present, the value must contain a valid media query list. The user agent will skip to the next source element if the value does not match the environment.